# AWS Lambda Nodejs fails with "Internal server error" on subsequent requests

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, lambda

Im running into an issue and for the life of me cannot see what's wrong.

I have a lambda nodejs function, and the first request works perfectly fine through api gateway, but for all subsequent requests it fails with the following:

```
response body:
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}

error message:
Tue Feb 04 11:11:57 UTC 2020 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 13 ms
Tue Feb 04 11:11:57 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Tue, 04 Feb 2020 11:11:57 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=4, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=d49a531a-74f6-4f9b-bce4-989e3c1bdbef, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5e39517d-e160bf769d459b3acfe72e31;sampled=0}
Tue Feb 04 11:11:57 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: null
Tue Feb 04 11:11:57 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Tue Feb 04 11:11:57 UTC 2020 : Gateway response type: DEFAULT_5XX with status code: 502
Tue Feb 04 11:11:57 UTC 2020 : Gateway response body: {"message": "Internal server error"}
```

My lambda function is written as follows:

```
const pg = require("pg");
const dbConfig = require('./config/db');
const format = require('pg-format');
const client = new pg.Client(dbConfig);
client.connect();

module.exports.putrequests = (event, context, callback) => {
  var body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var dates = body.date;
  var md5 = body.md5;
  var url = body.url;
  var email = body.email;
  var prepost = body.prepost;
  var status = "pending";

  const sql = 'INSERT into requests (date, md5, url, email, prepost) values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)';
  const values = [dates, md5, url, email, prepost];
  const query = client.query(sql, values, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
      callback(null, {
          statusCode: 500,
          headers: {
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: "Could not insert service " + err.stack
      });
    } else {
      console.log(res.rows[0]);
    }
  });
  query.on('row', (row, result) => {
    result.addRow(row);
  });
  query.on('end', result => {
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
    client.end();
    callback(null, {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "DB Insertion Successful"
    });
  });
  query.on('error', res => {
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: res.statusCode || 500,
        headers: {
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: "Could not insert service " + res.stack
    });
  });
};
```

does anyone have any ideas why this is failing on subsequent requests?

Comment: You should use `async/await` syntax, no need to use `callback`. Also do not end the client, the warm lambda can be called again and use the connection instead of opening a new one. Actually that will fail because of that

Answer (score 0):

the `body` should be a string. if you stringify the body, The api gateway will receive a successful error response instead of `502` response.

```
{
  body: "Could not insert service " + JSON.stringify(res.stack)
}
```

Comment: i dont know your table structure. The subsequent request could fail due to any primary key constraint (if you are trying to insert a key thats already existing)

Comment: Thanks Arun, tried the above and still the same issue, the first request is successful, all subsequent requests fail

Comment: what's the error message from the lambda logs (cloudwatch)

Comment: Hi Arun, managed to resolve it by removing the callback and rewriting the function. tHanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know why.
Since you are opening the client outside your function and then ending it after you finish the query, the next execution will fail because node-pg client won't be re-usable again after you close it: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1352